# Destroy a large amount of data as quickly as possible?

Tags: security, erase

How would you go about **securely** destroying *several hundred gigabytes* of arbitrary data as quickly as possible?

Incinerating hard drives is a slow, manual (and therefore insecure) process.

Comment: Are we assuming that there is only one copy of the data, and that it is held on a hard drive that you have physical access to?

Comment: are you looking for low-level formatting code?

Comment: @Jeff: yes and yes. @p.cambell: only if it's faster than fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically destroying the drives does not (necessarily) take a significant amount of time. Consider, for example, http://www.redferret.net/?p=14528 .

Comment: I don't think that is secure enough for all purposes. Also, I bet I could do better with a hammer or rock.

Comment: +1 just burn it, no one will ever get the data back...

Comment: @Luchaguate: I've never seen a citation of anyone actually recovering data manually from severely damaged platters. I propose that mangling the drive in such a fashion is sufficient for all purposes.

Comment: Point taken, I am probably not being realistic. Even if it were theoretically possible, it would likely be too expensive...

Comment: Blendtec might be a cheaper solution, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax2BOCoVDJk

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer but this seems like one of those questions best left unanswered unless you know why it's being asked.

Comment: The word "fired" may be a cause or a consequence :)